# Are $k$ points on a smooth algebraic plane curve ever in general position?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth plane curve of degree $d$ and genus $g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$. Let us choose $k\leq g+3d-1$ points on $C$. Is it true that the dimension of the space of plane curves of degree $d$ passing trough this $k$ points is of codimension $k$, i-e that this $k$ points are always in general position for plane curves of degree $d$? Can someone give me a proof of this fact?
Thanks!

Comment: What is $d$ ? It seems have nothing to do with $k$ and $g$.

Comment: It is the degree of the curve. I corrected my message, thanks for the remark.

Comment: If $g=1$, $d=3$, $k=9$, and the 9 points are the intersection of $C$ with another cubic, then this does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your remark. In fact the statement is not true if $k=g+3d-1$ and $g\geq 1$ and the points are contain in the intersection of $2$ curves of degree $d$.